# Connecting to IBM MQ SSL without .kdb file using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ibm-mq

I am using `MQ client 9.1` and able to successfully connect via SSL from my .Net application when I use `keystore.kdb` file.

My question is, can I still connect from .Net application if I don't use `keystore.kdb` file and instead just import SSL certificate in Windows machine?

I tried but can't find any syntax or way to do it so just curious if it is even possible?

**EDIT**

Here is relevant part of my code.

```
MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository = "*SYSTEM";
QProperties["CertificateLabel"] = "MyCert";
QProperties[MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY] = "*SYSTEM";
```

If I use `amqmdnet.dll` and run code then I get error `MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR`

If I use `amqmdnetstd.dll` and run code then I get error `MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE`

**EDIT**

After I enabled trace, I am getting following error in logs. TLS1.2 is enabled on this machine. No idea what is causing below error.

`The client and server cannot communicate because they do not possess a common algorithm`

**EDIT**

SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are disabled.

Only TLS 1.2 is enabled.

**EDIT**

I used the `SslTcpClient` example given below and it was throwing exact same error as mentioned above. Then I modified just one line of code and now I am able to connect. The trick was to define SSL protocol version 1.2. But how can I do the same in MQ?

**Example**

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=net-8.0`

**Original code which is throwing error**

`sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);`

**Modified code which worked**

`sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName, null, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);`

Comment: Hi Martin,  the answer below is not 100% correct.   If you use unmanaged mode then you have to use the kdb file.  If you use managed mode then you have to use the windows key store and specify either `*USER` for the user's certificates or `*SYSTEM` if you want to use the machine's certificates. The user will need to be granted access to the private key if using the machine certificates.

Comment: As using key db file works for Frank, doesn't that mean he is using the unmanaged .NET client? So I think your comment could be rather an alternative answer saying: switch to managed mode.

Comment: @JoshMc Is there an example of managed .Net code available?

Comment: If you use manged mode you should use one of the ANY* ciphers on the SVRCONN

Comment: @NineFriends I took it that he is currently using unmanaged mode but is asking for a way to use the windows key store,  switching to managed is a solution to that problem.

Comment: @JoshMc I understand, and that's why I was saying this may be an alternative answer, and not just a comment. One option is to accept there is no way to get rid of the database file (when using unmanaged), the other one is to switch to managed.

Comment: Feel free to add to your answer,  I'm too busy these days to give the effort for a proper answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are restricted to the key database file, I am afraid. This is documented in [MQ V.9.3 doc here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=mq-ssltls-key-repository). MQ V.9.1 doc tells the same, with the additional information that your version is out of support.